# llenar campos de un formulario con datos de una bd mysql al seleccionar un select

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

la idea es que al dar clic en alguna opcion de un select dependiendo de este me rellene los campos de  mi formulario estoy trabajando con php, mysql:
este es mi select

```
<select name="ruta" id="ruta" class="form-control" onchange="showService(this.value)">
        <?php 
          $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
          mysqli_select_db($link, "stp17");
          $tildes = $link->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); //Para que se muestren las tildes correctamente
          $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM rutas");
          while ($filas = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $filas['id']; ?>"><?php echo $filas['nomCorto']; ?></option>
            <?php                 
          }
          mysqli_free_result($result);
          mysqli_close($link);
        ?>
      </select>
```

En este div

```
<div id="nomCorto"></div>
```

alamaceno los datos pero no se como hacer para ponerlos en cajas de texto

Script

```
function showService(str) {
if (str=="") {
  document.getElementById("nomCorto").innerHTML="";

  return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    document.getElementById("nomCorto").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getservice.php?service="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

y este es mi archivo php

```
    <?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
   mysqli_select_db($link, "stp17");

$service = $_GET['service'];

$query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM rutas WHERE id = '".$service."'");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
?>
<p><?php echo $row['descripcion']; ?></p>
<?php
}

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: entiendo lo que me quieres decir, pero necesito más datos para poderte ayudar, como que tipo de conección estas usando, que campos tienes, como tienes tus campos en el sitio. etc

Comment: ya actualice la informacion es el codigo que llevo hasta ahora

Answer (score 1):

**SOBRE TU CÓDIGO**
1. No se entiende nada, pues está muy desorganizado.

**SUGERENCIA USANDO AJAX DE JQUERY**
1. Crea un form que contenga una Select, este debe tener un ID.
2. Crea un DIV con un ID dentro del form.
2. Usa  document ready de JQuery e implementa envio ajax hacia tu archivo php usando POST.
3. En el PHP captura los datos con POST.
4. Realiza la consulta usando MySQLi.
5. Con los datos que obtengas, puedes crear un String con los "nuevos" elementos que quieres que tenga formulario tal cual como si estuvieras en HTML y devolverlo a AJAX con Echo.
6. Los resultados devueltos lo colocas en el div que creaste con AJAX.

Este método a mi me funciona.

NOTA: Recuerda que al hacer esto los "nuevos" elementos son dinámicos a diferencia del select que creaste antes el cual es estático. Para que los nuevos elementos respondan a eventos en el JQuery deberás usar "On" para delegar eventos.

**SI ESTAS INTERESADO ME AVISAS PARA COLOCARTE CODIGO DE EJEMPLO**

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por comentar ya lo pude solucionar como queria